# How to force iOS scroll behavior on Android with Flutter?

Tags: flutter

In Android Flutter will add a `GlowingOverscrollIndicator` as a `ScrollBehavior`, I would like to know what's the name of the iOS `ScrollBehavior` that Flutter uses, as I can't find it on the repo and I would like to force it on both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 8):

**iOS scroll behavior set :**

```
physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
```

**Android scroll behavior set :**

```
physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
```

**depends on platform default scroll behavior set :**

```
physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: Is it possible to set this up globally?

Answer (score 2):

In order to force the iOS scroll behavior on a `ListView` or a `CustomScrollView`, just set:

```dart
physics: BouncingScrollPhysics()
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers:

to ensure that the ListView stays scrollable you should set AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics as a parent:

```
BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics())
```

Without this it did not work in my case.